# Runtime error '32' when trying to hover over one item to click a hidden button - Seleniumbasic / VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium in VBA to automatically click the expand button (bowtie) on a website - eventually to bring all that table data into excel.

I'm able to walk through every line of code and it's behaving correctly, except for this last line, when I try to select the hidden bowtie (maximize button in picture), I receive the Run-time error '32': Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
bot.FindElementByClass("richeditor-toolbar-button workitem-group-maximize").Click
```

I used the exact class provided when inspecting the bowtie - also tried a different class), but when I hit f8 - the session dies and the error pops up.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

```
Sub automation() Dim bot As New ChromeDriver, menuitem As WebElement 
bot.Get "https://company.visualstudio.com/" 
Set menuitem = bot.FindElementById("ui-id-38") 
bot.Actions.MoveToElement(menuitem).Perform 
bot.FindElementByClass("richeditor-toolbar-button workitem-group-maximize").Click
```

[screenshot of inspected bowtie element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fztf9.png)
[run time error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaPgn.png)

EDIT - played around a bit more and found that removing the last "div" from the class selector made it work. Adding screenshots of code for reference - this is an intranet site, so can't login without a company device - Screenshot 2 shows the inspected element I was trying to maximize.

I tried this version below as there were multiple versions of the bowtie on the page for other sections, removing the last div made it work.

This does not work because of the div at the end

```
bot.FindElementByCss("#vss_390 > div.tfs-collapsible-header.wit-form-group-header > button >div"
```

The below works since the div at the end was removed, though not sure why exactly

```
Set menuitem = bot.FindElementById("ui-id-38")
bot.Actions.MoveToElement(menuitem).Perform
bot.FindElementByCss("#vss_390 > div.tfs-collapsible-header.wit-form-group-header > button").Click
```

HTML Reference of page I was trying to work with [HTML Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91uzc.png)

Comment: I get not authorized if I try to access page. Can you use the snippet tool to include the actual HTML.

Comment: Thank you QHarr ! Looked like all it needed was to remove a div at the end of the problem line as there were multiple instances of the bowtie on the page. Not sure why exactly that made it work, but if anyone knows, would love to better understand